# Using a .bash_profile function in VS Code tasks

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code

I defined the following task in VS Code:

```
"label": "build",
"type": "shell",
"command": "opengl++ Interpolate.cpp"
```

where `opengl++()` is a bash function defined in `~/.bash_profile`. I am using MacOS High Sierra and the function works in *Terminal.app*. Executing this task gets:

> > Executing task: opengl++ Interpolate.cpp <
>
> /bin/bash: opengl++: command not found
>      The terminal process terminated with exit code: 127

Changing the task to:

```
"label": "build",
"type": "shell",
"command": "source ~/.bash_profile && opengl++ Interpolate.cpp"
```

fixes the problem, which makes it seem like the terminal isn't sourcing right. I tried deleting all user settings on VS Code to no avail.

This is not a viable fix. It seems dangerous to require explicitly sourcing `~/.bash_profile`. It seems this may cause problems when using build tasks for python (pyenv) and similar compilers that use `~/.bash_profile` to properly compile and forgetting to explicitly source.

How do I use functions defined in `~/.bash_profile` to work in VS Code shell tasks without prepending `source ~/.bash_profile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue on Linux and [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/20265) helped me.

Try adding

```
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.osx": [ "-l" ]
```

to your settings.json.

Comment: Thank you. I had ["-i"] set previously.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to create a script within the workspace in `.vscode`.
That script can contain organized and complicated commands.
Then, source the script in a task with a command similar to:

```
source .vscode/scripts/build.sh
```

Lines like `set -e` and `source ~/.bash_profile` among other things can be included in the script and we have a far cleaner `tasks.json`.